# The circle keeps getting stuck in the upper right corner of the rectangle

Tags: javascript

Whenever I try to run this function within my program, the circle (after it's own x position is passed the rectangles x position), will just get stuck in the upper right corner of the rectangle instead of bouncing off of it like I intended for it to do.

---

```
bounceOff: function(circle, rect) {
    let distX = Math.abs(circle.x - rect.x - rect.w / 2);
    let distY = Math.abs(circle.y - rect.y - rect.h / 2);
    circle.dx = distX - rect.w / 2;
    circle.dy = distY - rect.h / 2;
    return (circle.dx * circle.dx + circle.dy * circle.dy <= (circle.r * circle.r));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: `run this program` - that is an almost useless tiny snippet of a program, to be honest

Answer (score 0):

you must check Operator precedence. for example if:

```
circle.x = 10;
rect.x = 5;
rect.w = 6;
```

then

```
circle.x - rect.x - rect.w / 2
```

can result:  10 - (5-6/2) = 10 - 3 = 7

or: (10 - 5) - (6/2) = 5 - 3 = 2

or even: ((10-5) - 6) / 2 = -.5

use parentheses:

```
let distX = Math.abs(circle.x - (rect.x - (rect.w / 2)));
let distY = Math.abs(circle.y - (rect.y - (rect.h / 2)));
```

Comment: Actually your approach made it stop a lot earlier than it used to, like some invisible corner.

Comment: yes, it is only an example, change your operator precedence to  explain what you want (using parentheses) .